# convert int64 to float32 in c

Tags: c, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I read from an embedded device from four 16 bit registers that represent a 64 bit integer. The read function reads them in uint16_t and i want to convert it to float 32. If i do casting like this i get warnings left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default].

```
uint16_t u1,u2,u3,u4;
u1=readregister();
u2=readregister();
u3=readregister();
u4=readregister();

float num11 = (float) (u1 << 48);       
float num22 = (float) (u2 << 32); 
float num33 = (float) (u3 << 16);   
float num44 = (float) u4;   
float numm= num11+num22+num33+num44;
printf("%f\n", numm);
```

What about accuracy?

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
float num11 = (uint64_t) u1 << 48;
/* ... */
```

If the compiler warns (which C does not require) because of the `uint64_t` conversion to `float`, you can add an extra `float` cast:

```
float num11 = (float) ((uint64_t) u1 << 48);
```

This will get rid of the warning.

For efficiency and precision reasons, it would be best to first convert your 4 `uint16_t` to a single `uint64_t` and then perform a single conversion from  `uint64_t` to `float`.

Comment: I am not sure about efficiency, but building a single exact `uint64_t`  and then converting to float is definitely the most precise, for instance for `u4 == 1` and `u2 << 32 + u3 << 16` exactly midway between two representable `float`s.

Comment: Regarding efficiency, the question mentions an embedded device. Without a FPU all floating-point operations are done in software and require a lot of CPU cycles. A single runtime integer to `float` conversion is definitely better than four.

Comment: Right. I was thinking of the sort of embedded device that has an FPU but no native 64-bit integer type. :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is:

```
#include <math.h>

float numm = (float) u4 + ldexpf(u3, 16) + ldexpf(u2, 32) + ldexpf(u1, 48);
```

This does not require your embedded compiler to provide any other integer size than you already have with `uint16_t`, it only requires `ldexpf()`.

This computes a `float` that is within one ULP of the mathematical sum of the shifted integers `u1`, …, `u4`.

Comment: This causes multiple roundings and will not always produce the correctly rounded result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is right, hence my statement that the computed `float` is within one ULP of the mathematical sum.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is a way to do it that involves the “sticky bit” idea but it is too late in my time zone to dig it up now.

Comment: The sticky bit method partitions the bits to be rounded into four cases: “0 all-zeroes“, “0 not-all-zeros”, “1 all-zeroes”, and “1 not-all-zeros” and makes use of the fact that these are rounded in the same way as “00”, “01”, “10”, and “11”. Hence, to determine the rounding, one needs only the first bit to be rounded and the OR of the remaining bits. However, this requires determining which bits are to be rounded, which requires locating the highest bit set and counting 24 bits down from there.

Comment: Btw, you don't need ldexpf(). You can just multiply by e.g. 65536.0f, 4294967296.0f, 281474976710656.0f.